# Set the right crs on sf object to plot coordinate points

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, r

**UPDATE**
This question has already been answered on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232331/set-the-right-crs-on-sf-object-to-plot-coordinate-points/50240260#50240260).

I'm trying to define the right crs for my `sf` object. I want to plot points on the following layer (country: the Netherlands):

```
Simple feature collection with 380 features and 3 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 13565.4 ymin: 306846.2 xmax: 278026.1 ymax: 619232.6
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs
```

output:
[image]

This layer has the correct projection.

But the `POINT` layer doesn't have the correct crs project presumably because it has no `proj4string`?

```
Simple feature collection with 566 features and 5 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 3.5837 ymin: 50.86487 xmax: 7.120998 ymax: 53.44835
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
```

[image]

How do I set the same projection as the previous map so I can plot the coordinates points on it?

When I try it in QGIS and select the same crs for both maps they seem to be each on a whole different world.

[image]

Comment: The point data are in decimal degrees so probably WGS84 or ETRS89 or even Amersfoort.

Comment: In the last image they are both on Amersfort. How do I know which WGS84 or ETRS89?

Comment: RD New is based on Amersfoort but in meters. The other data is in decimal degrees, geographic CRS. You can't tell unless you can compare against known data. Either should be within a meter.

Comment: did you try sf::st_set_crs(your_point_layer, 4326) and then sf::st_transform(your_point_layer, "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs"

Comment: `Amersfoort` in this context means EPSG:4289 (in degrees), not the projected `RD New` coordinate system that is built on Amersfoort datum but uses meters.